# send message if user is in the database, reject if not

Tags: php

```
if (isset($submit)) {
  $getusers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register");
  while($getrows = mysql_fetch_array($getusers)) {
    $users = $getrows['username'];
    if ($touser == $users) {
      echo "$users";
      $send = $_GET['send'];
      if ($send == $one) {
        $query = mysql_query(
                   "INSERT INTO mailtbl VALUES 
                    (
                      '', '$touser', '$fromuser', '$subject', 
                      '$message', '0', '0', '1', '$date', '$rand'
                    )"
                 );
        $query2 = mysql_query(
                    "INSERT INTO mailtbl_admin VALUES 
                     (
                        '', '$touser', '$fromuser', '$subject', 
                        '$message', '0', '0', '1', '$date', '$rand'
                     )"
                  ); 
        $echo = "Message successfully sent."; 
      }
    } else {
      $echo = "There is no such user with the name of '$touser'";
    }
  }
  echo "$echo";
}
```

I am trying to write code that accepts the message to send to another user if the recipient is in my database. The problem is that I think my condition `(if ($touser == $users)` is wrong. `$touser` refers to my `$_POST['recipient']` in my form and `$users` refer to the users in the database.

Could someone please review my code to ensure I'm on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through all the users in your table, why don't you instead add a WHERE statement in your SQL command like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM register WHERE username = '" . $touser . "'"
```

If you get results send the message. If you get no results, display the 'no such user' message.

Also, if you are having trouble evaluating $touser to $user, try outputting the contents of $touser to make sure it's what you think it is.

```
print_r($touser);
```

Comment: You really should encourage the inquirer to use a prepared statement with variables, rather than building SQL by gluing strings together like this. This is exactly how you make SQL injection possible.